# Bootstrap is fixing height in header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I´m a designer with some coding skills, but far from being a programmer. Currently I´m working in a website based on a Bootstrap template, doing good enough except an issue that is driving me nuts: apparently Bootstrap´s CSS is overriding the site CSS, adding a fixed head in the index.html header, which contains a div that contains an image carousel.

Displaying the site in small devices (tablets and cell phones), the carousel hides properly using "hidden-xs" and "hidden-xm" classes, but the header remains with a fixed height of 929px as Element Inspector shows, generating a very tall empty space before the next section.

Below you´ll find the header code, including carousel:

```
<header id="intro">


<!-- CAROUSEL STARTS -->
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide hidden-xs hidden-xm" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000" style="border:1px solid red;">

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <div class="item active">
     <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/header-01.jpg" align="left" alt="Slide 01">
      <!-- <div class="carousel-caption">
        <p>El conocimiento es libertad</p>
      </div> -->
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/header-02.jpg" alt="Slide 02">
      <!-- <div class="carousel-caption">
        <p>El respeto a sí mismo</p>
      </div> -->
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/header-03.jpg" alt="Slide 03">
      <!-- <div class="carousel-caption">
        <p>El respeto a los demás</p>
      </div> -->
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/header-04.jpg" alt="Slide 04">
      <!-- <div class="carousel-caption">
        <p>Jardín - Primaria -  Secundaria</p>
      </div> -->
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/header-05.jpg" alt="Slide 05">
      <!-- <div class="carousel-caption">
        <p>El conocimiento es libertad</p>
      </div> -->
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/header-06.jpg" alt="Slide 06">
      <!-- <div class="carousel-caption">
        <p>El respeto a sí mismo</p>
      </div> -->
    </div>

     <!-- Wrapper for slides ENDS -->

  </div>

<!-- CAROUSEL ENDS -->
</div>

</header>
```

And a couple of screenshots:

[Home page full size (index.html)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kUdw.jpg)

[image]

[Home page small devices width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTowH.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this in your `CSS` file

```
#intro {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

This should override the default `height` pixel.

If you want to have the fullscreen image, then write like this

```
#intro {
  height: 100vh !important;
}
```

Hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: That worked great, thank you so much! I´ve tried it before but without the "!important" line...

Comment: Now I have another problem, the following section div "hides" partially below the navbar, how can I fix this?

Comment: You're welcome, please verify my answer so that if anyone comes to an issue like this, can find a solution. About the other `div`, you need to learn **CSS positioning**, `margins`, `paddings` and `display` properties. Those are the properties that align elements properly on a webpage. You can learn about them here http://cssreference.io/ , or you can learn them on freeCodeCamp or codecademy, or you can post another question on stack overflow with your issue.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it using hide and show properties depending display size. I already voted your answer, but apparently my vote doesn´t display in the public score because I´m short on reputation, at least 15 points are needed. (just signed in today to get help with this very issue)

Comment: Ok, glad that you were able to fix it. No, not "vote", but to "verify", it look like a "check" sign or "Nike" brand right below where you vote the answer.

Comment: OK, found it and verified your answer. Thanks again!